# Integrate Web service (.svc)

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2005

I had a .svc file which my end user gave to me for integration of a web service.
I try most of the way the internet mention which is to 'add a web service' but i keep getting an error as follows

The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
  - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
  - There was an error downloading 'http://someAddress/VFCSMTStep2StripService/MapManagementServices.svc?xsd=xsd0'.
  - The remote name could not be resolved: 'someAddress'

I believe the address is intended to be use within an internal web service.
Does that mean if i cannot connect to that address i cannot carry on the programming as it does not allow me to create and web reference. I am using VS2005. 
Do point me to any link if this question is a repeat.

Thanks

Comment: If the webservice doesn't allow you to add its web reference then how would you access it internally? I think there could be some problem while adding reference, have you asked them (the one who provided the document )about this issue?

Comment: I believe the address is used within the end user domain and not exposed to the outside Internet.